# Counting Based on 3 Conditions

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a dataset and would like to count 3 separate conditions

1. Number of Rows with "0s" in both columns `coins` and `copay` - counting N/A in either column as a 0
2. Number of Rows where `coins.copay` column = 1, but excludes values that satisfy condition 1
3. Number of Rows where `coins.copay` column = 0, but excludes values that satisfy condition 1

Here's a sample from the much larger dataset:

```
Plan   Year   Coins   Copay   Type   Coins.Copay
 A     2018     0      NA      HMO        1
 B     2018    10      NA      HMO        1
 C     2017    NA       0      SNP        0
 D     2015    20      20      SNP        0
 E     2016    20       0      HMO        1
 F     2018    10      10      HMO        0
 G     2016    NA      NA      HMO        0
 H     2014    NA      NA      HMO        0
 I     2012    NA      10      PPO        0
 J     2011     0       0      HMO        0
 K     2014     5      10      SNP        0
 L     2013    10      NA      HMO        1
```

Thus, I would like to have the following counts (based on conditions above):

1. 5 (Plans A, C, G, H, J satisfy the condition)
2. 3 (Plans B, E, L satisfy the condition; Plan A not counted as it satisfied condition 1)
3. 4 (Plans D, F, I, K satisfy the condition; Plans C, G, H, J not counted as they satisfied condition 1)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This can be done very efficiently using just boolean logic:

```
zeros_or_na <- (is.na(df$Coins) | !df$Coins) & (is.na(df$Copay) | !df$Copay)
sum(zeros_or_na)                     # [1] 5
sum(df$Coins.Copay & !zeros_or_na)   # [1] 3
sum(!df$Coins.Copay & !zeros_or_na)  # [1] 4
```

Answer (score 2):

One option could be as:

> Approach:
>
> 1.Use `&` within inner condition so decision will be fast.
>
> 2.Filter for condition `2&3` so filter is applied only once.
>
> 3.Once condition `2&3` have been calculated using filtered data, subtract the their `sum` from total row count to get count for
>   condition-1

```
Excluded_conditino_one = which((!is.na(df$Coins) & 
                  df$Coins) | (!is.na(df$Copay) & df$Copay))


coins.copay_1 = sum(df[Excluded_conditino_one,"Coins.Copay"]==1) #3
coins.copay_0 = sum(df[Excluded_conditino_one,"Coins.Copay"]==0) #4


Condition_One = length(df$Plan) - (coins.copay_1+coins.copay_0)  #5


#Test
paste(Condition_One, coins.copay_1, coins.copay_0)
[1] "5 3 4"
```

**Workbench Analysis for performance:**

```
CBarun <- function(df){
  zeros_or_na <- (is.na(df$Coins) | !df$Coins) & (is.na(df$Copay) | !df$Copay)
  Condition_One = sum(zeros_or_na)                     # [1] 5
  coins.copay_1 = sum(df$Coins.Copay & !zeros_or_na)   # [1] 3
  coins.copay_0 = sum(!df$Coins.Copay & !zeros_or_na)  # [1] 4
}


Masoud <- function(df){
  Condition_One = length(which(rowSums(cbind(df$Coins, df$Copay), na.rm=T)==0)) #5

  coins.copay_1 = length(which(rowSums(cbind(df$Coins, df$Copay), na.rm=T)!=0 &
  df$Coins.Copay!=0)) #3

  coins.copay_0 = length(which(rowSums(cbind(df$Coins, df$Copay), na.rm=T)!=0 &
  df$Coins.Copay==0))   
}

MKR <- function(df){

  Excluded_conditino_one = which((!is.na(df$Coins) &
          df$Coins) | (!is.na(df$Copay) & df$Copay))

  coins.copay_1 = sum(df[Excluded_conditino_one,"Coins.Copay"]==1) #3
  coins.copay_0 = sum(df[Excluded_conditino_one,"Coins.Copay"]==0) #4


  Condition_One = length(df$Plan) - (coins.copay_1+coins.copay_0)  #5
}


library(microbenchmark)

microbenchmark(CBarun(df),
               #AyushNigam(),
               Masoud(df),
               MKR(df),
               times = 10
)

# Unit: microseconds
#       expr     min      lq     mean   median      uq     max neval
# CBarun(df)  60.790  61.185  71.7644  62.7645  67.896 137.370    10
# Masoud(df) 185.923 186.317 209.9624 201.3180 222.633 273.949    10
# MKR(df)    101.054 102.633 122.1330 106.1850 121.975 227.370    10
```

**Data**

```
df <- read.table(text = 
"Plan   Year   Coins   Copay   Type   Coins.Copay
A     2018     0      NA      HMO        1
B     2018    10      NA      HMO        1
C     2017    NA       0      SNP        0
D     2015    20      20      SNP        0
E     2016    20       0      HMO        1
F     2018    10      10      HMO        0
G     2016    NA      NA      HMO        0
H     2014    NA      NA      HMO        0
I     2012    NA      10      PPO        0
J     2011     0       0      HMO        0
K     2014     5      10      SNP        0
L     2013    10      NA      HMO        1",
header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Comment: Quoting: *"microseconds benchmarks are meaningless in R Because some functions have an overhead when you initiate them. The fact that some function doesn't have a few microseconds overhead on a tiny data set doesn't mean it will scale the same on a huge data set.In other words, a user can't feel this tiny overhead anyway, but they can feel an overhead of minutes vs seconds on big data sets. Hence, benchmarks should be at-least in milliseconds, if not more."*

Answer (score 1):

Another option would be using `length` with `rowSums`:

```
length(which(rowSums(cbind(df$Coins, df$Copay), na.rm=T)==0)) #5

length(which(rowSums(cbind(df$Coins, df$Copay), na.rm=T)!=0 & df$Coins.Copay!=0)) #3

length(which(rowSums(cbind(df$Coins, df$Copay), na.rm=T)!=0 & df$Coins.Copay==0)) #4
```

Comment: I did benchmark on performance. Have a look and let me know if you will like to tweak anything from your logic.

Comment: @MKR I left a comment under your post.